# Reactjs, sending and reading variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so basically I'm using ref to get component dimensions in `componentDidMount()` and I can read and *console.log* that and it gives me the **width** I want(look into code), but when I want to read and *console.log* that in the `render()` method and to use that informations, it gives me **undefined**. And I don't know what is wrong

```js
var Tooltip = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tooltipSize = this.refs.tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.tooltipWidth = this.tooltipSize.width;
    // console.log(this.tooltipWidth); here it gives me the width
  },

  render(){
    var tooltipSize,
        tooltipWidth,
        tooltipStyle = {
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
        };
        // console.log(tooltipWidth); here it gives me undefined
    return(
      <div ref="tooltip" className="tooltip" style={tooltipStyle}>{this.props.tooltip}</div>
    );
  }
});

var Button = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          iconStyle: this.props.iconStyle,
         style: this.props.style,
          cursorPos: {},
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.size = this.refs.button.getBoundingClientRect();
   this.width = this.size.width;
    this.height = this.size.height;
    this.top = this.size.top;
   this.left = this.size.left;
  },

  ...
  
  render() {

    var _props = this.props,
      top,
      left,
      width,
      height,
      size,
     //other variables
  ...

     return(
        <Style>
        {`
          .IconButton{
            position: relative;
          }
          .IconButton:disabled{
            color: ${_props.disabledColor};
          }
          .btnhref{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
          }
        `}
        <a {...opts} className="btnhref" id="tak">
         <button ref="button" className={"IconButton" + _props.className} disabled={disabled} style={buttonStyle}
         onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave={this.removeTooltip} >
           <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
           <FontIcon className={_props.iconClassName}/>
         </button>
        </a>
        </Style>
  );

  }
});

class IconButton extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <Tooltip tooltip={this.props.tooltip} />
      <Button href={this.props.href} className={this.props.className} iconStyle={this.props.iconStyle} style={this.props.style} iconClassName={this.props.iconClassName} disabled={this.props.disabled} disableTouchRipple={this.props.disableTouchRipple} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**And one thing else.** How can I send variables with informations about dimensions of another component(Button component) to the Tooltip component? Because I need to use them inside of this component to place it. Thanks

**Updated code:**

```js
var Tooltip = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
        tooltipWidth: null,
        tooltipHeight: null
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tooltipSize = this.refs.tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({
      tooltipWidth: this.tooltipSize.width,
      tooltipHeight: this.tooltipSize.height
    });
  },

...
  
  render(){
    var _props = this.props,
        fontSize,
        fontStyle,
        tooltipSize,
        tooltipWidth = this.state.tooltipWidth,
        tooltipHeight = this.state.tooltipHeight,
        w = this.props.buttonWidth,
        h = this.props.buttonHeight,
        y = this.props.buttonTop,
        x = this.props.buttonLeft,
        tooltipStyle = {
            top: y - tooltipHeight - 20 + "px",
            left: x - tooltipWidth/2 + w/2 + "px",
          };;

...

    return(
      <div ref="tooltip" className="tooltip" style={fontStyle}>{this.props.tooltip}</div>
    );
  }
});

var Button = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
      return {
          iconStyle: this.props.iconStyle,
         style: this.props.style,
          cursorPos: {},
          width: null,
          height: null,
          top: null,
          left: null,
      };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    this.size = this.refs.button.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.width = this.size.width;
    this.height = this.size.height;
    this.top = this.size.top;
    this.left = this.size.left;
  },

  transferring1(){
    var width = this.width;
    return width;
  },

  transferring2(){
    var height = this.height;
    return height;
  },

  transferring3(){
    var top = this.top;
    return top;
  },

  transferring4(){
    var left = this.left;
    return left;
  },

...
  
  render() {

    var _props = this.props,
      opts,
      top,
      left,
      width,
      height,
      size;

...
  
     return(
        <Style>
        {`
          .IconButton{
            position: relative;
          }
          .IconButton:disabled{
            color: ${_props.disabledColor};
          }
          .btnhref{
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: blue;
          }
        `}
        <a {...opts} className="btnhref" id="tak">
         <button ref="button" className={"IconButton" + _props.className} disabled={disabled} style={buttonStyle}
         onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave={this.removeTooltip} >
           <Ink background={true} style={rippleStyle} opacity={rippleOpacity} />
           <FontIcon className={_props.iconClassName}/>
         </button>
        </a>
        </Style>
  );

  }
});

class IconButton extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      buttonWidth: null,
      buttonHeight: null,
      buttonTop: null,
      buttonLeft: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      buttonWidth: this.refs.btn.transferring1(),
      buttonHeight: this.refs.btn.transferring2(),
      buttonTop: this.refs.btn.transferring3(),
      buttonLeft: this.refs.btn.transferring4(),
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
    <div>
      <Tooltip tooltipPosition={this.props.tooltipPosition} tooltip={this.props.tooltip} touch={this.props.touch} buttonWidth={this.state.buttonWidth} buttonHeight={this.state.buttonHeight} buttonTop={this.state.buttonTop} buttonLeft={this.state.buttonLeft}/>
      <Button ref="btn" href={this.props.href} className={this.props.className} iconStyle={this.props.iconStyle} style={this.props.style} iconClassName={this.props.iconClassName}
      disabled={this.props.disabled} disableTouchRipple={this.props.disableTouchRipple} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
 <IconButton href="" className="" iconStyle="" style="" iconClassName="face" disabled="" disableTouchRipple="" tooltip="! ! ! Guzik ! to ! kozak ! ! !" tooltipPosition="" touch="true" />,
 document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use state for setting variables in react

example

```
var Tooltip = React.createClass({
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {tooltipWidth: 0}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.tooltipSize = this.refs.tooltip.getBoundingClientRect();
    this.setState({tooltipWidth: this.tooltipSize.width}); //Update the state of this component
  },

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.tooltipWidth) //your tooltip width
    return(
      <div ref="tooltip" className="tooltip" style={tooltipStyle}>{this.props.tooltip}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

and for passing another's component dimension, you should calculate the size of Button component on the parent component (IconButton).

Then pass it to Tooltip like this (just example)

```
<Tooltip buttonHeight={this.state.buttonHeight} tooltip={this.props.tooltip} />
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but now I'm getting this error: **Uncaught Error: ReactClassInterface: You are attempting to define `constructor` on your component more than once. This conflict may be due to a mixin.**

Comment: Hi @Karol it's probably because you have more than 1 constructor in your component. oh and I updated the answer to include `super()` right after the constructor

Comment: Hi @kendrickkesley, thanks, I found a solution before, but now I have problem. So basically I've created a function in the **Button** component which returns a object and after I call this function in parent class in `componentDidMount()` like this: `this.setState({
      buttonDim: this.refs.btn.transferring(),
    });` And now I have this in state which I pass into Tooltip component, and here I get reference to this: `var options = this.props.buttonDim;` and it's object under **options** and I can console.log this and it gives me the right object. To be continued(too long for one comment)

Comment: cont... I want to use things from this object and to save them in variables: `var  w = options.width;` but it gives me an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null` and I don't know what to do :(

Comment: Hi @Karol where did you declare `var options = this.props.buttonDim;`? I might be wrong but I'm assuming that you declare that on the constructor and access the `options` on different function e.g `render()`. If it's the case, you should put the width into the component's state instead of `var options`. Please tell me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi @kendrickkesley, I declare **options** inside `render()` od button, and it works because I can **consloe.log** options and it gives me the right objects, but what I mean is that I cannot get reference to its property like this `options.width` or like this `this.props.buttonDim.width`. I just can't do this with the state. I've found a way around that, I mean I solved this problem but in a worse way. For each element for this object I creacted its own function which has returned this and I'ce declared it like **options** and I can normally use that. But I don't like this solution.

Comment: Hmm.. that's kind of weird.. Can you update your question with the code?